# Error with two selectManyListbox

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two selectManyListbox related(the second is generated accordind the first) ,but when
I run the application an error occure:

**JSF:**

```
<h:selectManyListbox   value="#{TestAjax.selectedProjects}"  id="project" size="3">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select Projects -- " itemValue="0"/> 
  <f:selectItems value="#{TestAjax.getMyListProject()}" />
  <f:ajax event="change"  render="status" />
 </h:selectManyListbox>

 <h:selectManyListbox   value="#{TestAjax.selectedstatus}" id="status"  size="3">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select status -- " itemValue="0"/> 
  <f:selectItems value="#{TestAjax.StepsByProject()}" />
 </h:selectManyListbox>
```

**The error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at DAOKPI.TestAjax.FormattingVar(TestAjax.java:342)
at DAOKPI.TestAjax.StepsByProject(TestAjax.java:367)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:737)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:467)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:254)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:111)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:202)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:135)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:762)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:844)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:298)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java    :312)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:55)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:229)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:152)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:75)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingSt     rategy.java:401)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
```

Comment: Just curious, how/where did you learn Java (EE) / JSF? Most of exposed coding styles and practices made me almost cry.

Comment: I haven't write this code ,I'am just tring to adjust the code to the JSF UI ,I felt ashamed by asking:( I will re-write it and re-ask again:)

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at DAOKPI.TestAjax.FormattingVar(TestAjax.java:342)
at DAOKPI.TestAjax.StepsByProject(TestAjax.java:367)
```

This tells you all you need to know. A null pointer exception occured in your class TestAjax, the method was FormattingVar() and the line number is 342.
From your JSF page, the error occured in the 2nd selectManyListbox, as seen by the StepsByProject() in the stacktrace as well